# Cut too big a hole in drywall for socket

Tags: drywall, hole, socket

New to home improvements here so bear with me. I cut a hole to put in a new socket, but it seems the hole I cut was just a bit too big. The socket wings almost cover the entire area, but not quite:

[image]

So I am not sure what my options are here. Is there an some kind of attachment that could go on the wings, or some thing piece of material that could span across the width of the wings, but still thin enough to fit under the plate cover?

EDIT - Some photos of the GFI socket I bought:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is that cable coming out?  Do you have an electrical box in that hole?  Besides those two, the hole does not look that big, the face plate will probably cover it once the cable is moved.  That cable will probably need to be moved

Comment: @crip659 That is the conduit cable for the power that has not been connected yet. The hole has nothing in it, just the conduit cable coming out for later when we connect it to that GFI socket I bought. The socket is just there in picture to show scale of the hole. The socket doesn't appear to be big enough to get to the edges of the hole I cut.

Comment: EDIT - I added some photos of the socket to the post

Comment: Actually, your hole is too _small_ to fit a single gang old-work junction box in there. But, don't worry, that's a much easier fix than a hole that's too big.

Comment: Please don’t take this wrong, but I’d suggest a little background reading on home electrical wiring. It’s pretty easy to make dangerous mistakes.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate that is why I'm here. I've also spoken to several people at the hardware store. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't be too big once you install the **old-work junction box** you appear to have decided you don't need.

[image: old-work box]

*image source https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/32809eab-094f-44e1-9f37-9a1d4fd458f7/svn/boxes-brackets-cdowtg-16r-64_1000.jpg no endorsement implied*

You DO need that, unless you make a bigger hole to put a new-work style box into and patch the wall after.

You'll also need to route the AC, BX, MC, or MC-lite cable properly into a clamp on the box.

And if or when you *really* manage to overdo a hole for a one-gang box, you can usually install a 2-gang box and put a one-side-blank trim plate on it. Or a 4 x 4 or 4-11/16 x 4-11/16 box with a one-gang mud ring.

Comment: If the hole were cut to proper size would I still need a work junction box?

Comment: Absolutely, positively, without a doubt, 100% **YES**, @KalamalkaKid. Unless you happen to like catching your house on fire. I presume you're in the USA, based on the outlets, and a box has been required by the NEC for _decades_ for safety. You'll want to use a _metal_ box so you can properly attach that cable, and you'll need to use the proper clamp to attach it to protect the wires inside the metal housing.

Comment: Ok then a box it is !

Comment: Can you explain how a box helps prevent fires (if you are inclined to answer).

Comment: would this work? https://www.homedepot.ca/product/iberville-single-gang-device-box-3-in-x-2-in-x-2-1-2-in-deep/1000106202?rrec=true

Comment: You linked to a new-work box, designed to be nailed into a stud before drywall goes on. Old-work boxes have clamps that attach them to drywall already in place. Boxes help prevent fires by containing arcing from bad connections away from combustible wood. Metal boxes contain those arcs better, and also lead to the fault causing the breaker to trip in more cases when the loose wire comes into contact with the grounded metal box.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this., as it is really important for safety! Do you think this would work? https://www.homedepot.ca/product/iberville-gangable-device-box-3-in-x-2-in-x-2-1-2-in-deep/1000106199?searchterm=1000106199

Comment: The second one does seem to be a version of an old-work box designed to mount to plaster or drywall, yes.

Comment: I mean, if the cable is staying outside the wall, the OP might as well run with a *surface* mount box, no?

Comment: @Huesmann the cable will not be outside the wall.

Comment: Oh, so that cable is coming out of the wall, not going into the wall.